# Finding whithout loop the next highest and the next smallest number of a number in a one-dimensional table in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, max, min

am asking if there is a function in matlab which finds the first max and first min numbers compered to a number in an array

example :

if we have an array **A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];**

and the number is **x=3.4;**

How can we find whith a function (and not with a loop) and store the fist min and firts max of x in variables min_x  max_x ?

**desirable results:**

**min_x = 3**

**max_x = 4**

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, do you want to find the largest and smallest digit in a decimal number?

Answer (score 3):

Use logical indexing to select the entries of `A` smaller (larger) than `x`, and then use `max` (`min`):

```
max(A(A-x<0))
min(A(A-x>0))
```

I'm interpreting "next highest/smallest" as the closest numbers to `x` in `A`, from above and from below.

Comment: Thank you very much this is the answer i was looking for :)
just fount it ..

min_x=A(max(find(A < x)))

max_x=A((max(find(A < x)))+2)

Answer (score 0):

First you'll probably want to convert the decimal to an array. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360462/convert-decimal-number-to-vector) are some suggested ways that you can do this. After you have an array of your digits, you should be able to juse use MATLAB's built in max() and min() functions.

Comment: Thank you very much this is the answer i was looking for :)
just fount it ..

min_x=A(max(find(A < x)))

max_x=A((max(find(A < x)))+2)