# MatLab - variable precision arithmetic

Tags: matlab, numbers, arbitrary-precision

I have a brief question regarding the `vpa` command one may use to evaluate symbolic expressions in MatLab.

My textbook says the following:

"You need to be careful when you use functions such as `sqrt` on numbers, which by default result in a double-precision floating-point number.  You need to pass such input to `vpa` as a symbolic string for correct evaluation: `vpa('sqrt(5)/pi')`."

I don't quite understand the jargon here.  Why is it that for most inputs I get the exact same answer whether I type `vpa(input)` or `vpa('input')`, but not for square roots?  For instance, if I type `vpa(sin(pi/4))` or `vpa('sin(pi/4)')`, I get the exact same answers, but if I type the give problem above as `vpa(sqrt(5)/pi)`, I do not get the same answer as when I type `vpa('sqrt(5)/pi')`.

If someone could explain this in a little more detail than what my book does above, I would be very grateful!

Comment: you might be interested to read this question: [In MATLAB, are variables REALLY double-precision by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4227145/97160)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no MatLab expert, but without quotes, you're passing the *result* of `sqrt(5)/pi` into `vpa()`:

```
  vpa(sqrt(5)/pi)
= vpa(0.7117625434171772)
```

With quotes, you're passing the *expression* `sqrt(5)/pi` (unevaluated and in exact form) into `vpa()` and then telling MatLab to compute `sqrt(5)/pi` with variable precision.

Comment: Thanks!  That makes sense.  However, why is it that when I enter simply sin(pi/4) into vpa, that it doesn't matter whether or not I use quotes?

Comment: It should matter. As @Ben Volgt pointed out, `sin(pi / 4) = sin(45 deg) = sqrt(2) / 2`, which is irrational and won't be exactly approximated by double precision floats.

Comment: After reading [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/vpa.html) it sounds like `vpa` returns a double-precision result, in which case only the precision of intermediate values is improved.

Comment: Great.  Much appreciated!  I think I get this now :)

Answer (score 11):

Never assume that a number like vpa(sin(pi/4)) is exact to the full precision, because MATLAB will generally compute the number inside the call to vpa using floating point arithmetic, so only accurate to about 16 digits.

However, it appears that it is correct here. For example, we know that

```
sin(pi/4) == sqrt(2)/2
```

Lets test that result. I'll use 100 digits of precision, comparing both vpa and my own HPF tools.

```
>> vpa(sin(pi/4),100)
ans =
0.7071067811865475244008443621048490392848359376884740365883398689953662392310535194251937671638207864

>> vpa(sqrt(sym(2))/2,100)
ans =
0.7071067811865475244008443621048490392848359376884740365883398689953662392310535194251937671638207864

>> sqrt(hpf(2,100))/2
ans =
0.7071067811865475244008443621048490392848359376884740365883398689953662392310535194251937671638207864

>> sin(hpf('pi',100)/4)
ans =
0.7071067811865475244008443621048490392848359376884740365883398689953662392310535194251937671638207864
```

So, my guess is the parser has recognized the input as something the symbolic toolbox can compute more accurately. As I said before, be careful though. What is sin(pi/12)?

```
>> vpa(sin(pi/12),100)
ans =
0.25881904510252073947640383266843855381011962890625

>> vpa('sin(pi/12)',100)
ans =
0.2588190451025207623488988376240483283490689013199305138140032073150569747488019969223679746942496655

>> vpa(sin(sym('pi')/12),100)
ans =
0.2588190451025207623488988376240483283490689013199305138140032073150569747488019969223679746942496655

>> sin(hpf('pi',100)/12)
ans =
0.2588190451025207623488988376240483283490689013199305138140032073150569747488019969223679746942496655
```

See that in the first case, the parser did not save us. In the others, I forced MATLAB to compute the correct value. In fact, a bit of effort will give us the value for sin(pi/12), as sqrt(2)*(sqrt(3) - 1)/4.

```
>> DefaultNumberOfDigits 100
>> (sqrt(hpf(3)) - 1)*sqrt(hpf(2))/4
ans =
0.2588190451025207623488988376240483283490689013199305138140032073150569747488019969223679746942496655
```

The point is, do not trust the parser to save you here.

Edit: As a test of Amro's comment, I respectfully state that MATLAB IS doing something of interest here. See that vpa is able to return the correct first 100 digits of pi, even when passed pi as a double precision number. Since pi (as a double) is not correct past about the 16th decimal digit, there is something fishy going on.

```
>> vpa(pi,100)
ans =
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068

>> vpa('pi',100)
ans =
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068

vpa('pi',100) - vpa(pi,100)
ans =
0.0
```

As a test of that fact, lets look at what HPF finds. HPF actually takes the IEEE 754 value, as stored in a double, then converts it to an HPF number.

```
>> hpf(pi,100)
ans =
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875

>> hpf('pi',100)
ans =
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068

>> hpf('pi',100) - hpf(pi,100)
ans =
0.0000000000000001224646799147353177226065932275001058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480800000000
```

So clearly, MATLAB is able to recognize pi as something more than just the double precision value it will be passed in as.

Edit2:

In fact, a bit of play tells me what is happening here. VPA is the tricky one, not the parser. Consider the fraction 7/13. If we build it as a double, then print out the floating point value stored in its full glory, we see it is not truly exact. This is as expected.

```
>> sprintf('%.100f',7/13)
ans =
0.5384615384615384359179302009579259902238845825195312500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

7/13 is a repeating decimal value. Here are the correct digits:

```
>> vpa('7/13',100)
ans =
0.5384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615385
```

Now, suppose we try to create the same number. Here I'll pass 7/13 in asa double, but I'll make a mistake in the bottom decimal digits

```
>> sprintf('%.100f',0.538461538461538461777777777)
ans =
0.5384615384615384359179302009579259902238845825195312500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Here we see that vpa catches and corrects the 'error' I've made, recognizing that what I passed in is actually identically the same value as when I passed in 7/13.

```
>> vpa(0.538461538461538461777777777,100)
ans =
0.5384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615385
```

Of course, if I pass in the value as a string, then vpa gets it wrong.

```
>> vpa('0.538461538461538461777777777',100)
ans =
0.538461538461538461777777777
```

This explains why vpa is able to catch and correctly compute vpa(sin(pi/4),100), out to the full precision asked. sin(pi/4) is computed as a double, but then vpa sees it as a number that is the same as a double precision version of sqrt(2)/2.

Be careful of course. For example, vpa is not smart enough to catch this simple shift of pi.

```
>> vpa(pi + 1,100)
ans =
4.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875

>> vpa(pi,100)
ans =
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068
```

Comment: just to clear any confusion, the parser does not treat the input in `vpa(sin(pi/4))` any different from calling any other function `myFcn(sin(pi/4))`... MATLAB first evaluates the expression in double precision before passing the result to the function. With finite precision, the result is rounded to the nearest decimal value it can represent, which VPA treats as an exact value. At that point it can calculate as much decimal points as you wish... I believe [@AndrewJanke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4227530/97160) gave a good explanation in the question I linked to.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I truly appreciate your detailed answer.

Comment: @woodchips: it seems you are also correct. When you call `vpa` with a numeric expression, it internally calls `vpa(sym(expr))`. Now when `sym` is called with a number, it tries to convert the number to "rational" form in order to compensate for round-off error ([flag = 'r'](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/sym.html#inputarg_flag) argument), which explains why VPA "corrected" the error as you showed. If you want to get the same results as your HPF tool, I guess it would be: `vpa(sym('pi')-sym(pi,'d'), 100)`

Comment: @woodchips: No wonder I've missed this detail, looking at the documentation in [previous versions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011b/toolbox/symbolic/sym.html), it wasn't obvious that such conversion was taking place, and its not until R2012a that the doc mentions this fact clearly... +1 for a really enlightening answer

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the exact same answer, you didn't need variable precision arithmetic to begin with.

However, `sin(pi/4)` should be exactly `sqrt(2)/2`, which is irrational.  You should not get exactly the same answer from different precision.  Perhaps you should check how you're displaying (and rounding off) the result.

Comment: Thanks.  I get this now :).  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The latest doc on [numeric to symbolic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/numeric-to-symbolic-conversion-1.html) conversion has the answer.

> sym tries to correct the round-off error in floating-point inputs to
>   return the exact symbolic form. Specifically, sym corrects round-off
>   error in numeric inputs that match the forms p/q, pπ/q, (p/q)^(1/2), 2^q,
>   and 10^q, where p and q are modest-sized integers.

Thus, `sin(pi/4)` is `2^(1/2)/2` or `(1/2)^(1/2)` so the `vpa` command recognizes it. However, `sqrt(5)/pi` is not a recognized input form according to the doc.