# 'exact' numerical value after numerical optimization MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, format, double

I'm having the following issue with my code. I've been trying to use some other posts that I found on line, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227145/in-matlab-are-variables-really-double-precision-by-default). But they didn't what I'm looking for.

My code uses a MATLAB Exchange function which optimize a numerical value that is important to be with 32 digits after the dot such as

```
0.59329669191989231613604260928696
```

The optimization function can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8277-fminsearchbnd-fminsearchcon) and it is called `fminsearchbnd`
The optimization function calculate this and store the value in a variable that I use all over my code. In order not to perform the optimization everytime I want to store the variable (I tried either on a *.mat and on a label in the string form.
But when I retrieve it, MATLAB transforms it in a double precision variable 'cutting' all the numbers after the 14th. However I need all of them because they are important!

Is it possible to read a number like that w/o using `vpa()` because with a symbolic value I can't do anything.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT:
`fminsearchbnd` gives me this `class(bb)` -> `double` and when I want to see it on the workspace it is `0.586675392365899`. But when I set `formatSpec = '%.32f\n';` because I want to see all the numbers that the optimization gives me, typing `set(editLabel,'String',num2str(bb,formatSpec))`

Comment: Those final digits you claim to want are nothing but numerical garbage. What do you want to use them for?

Comment: I know that 32 digits are numerical garbage, but when I round it to 14 digits (double precision in matlab) my solution changes :(

Comment: It feels there's more going on here than meets the eye...feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you perhaps post a minimal working example of the whole optimization, including where you save/load the result?

Comment: Have you scaled the parameters in your optimization? See [this](http://www.alglib.net/optimization/tipsandtricks.php#header1) and [this](http://www.alglib.net/optimization/scaling.php).

Comment: I *think* you stumbled upon a bug in `fminsearchbnd`. I've written a very similar function based on `fminsearchcon`, and one of the many initial bugs I encountered was that the results remained scaled/transformed to the internal algorithms wrapped around `fminsearch`. These functions work by applying transformations to your variables, *mimicking* the behavior of bounds/constraints. The results you find may simply not have been transformed back properly. Could you try to do the optimization again with [my tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24298-optimize)?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I'll try thank you very much. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to store/use a number that cannot be represented exactly in an [IEEE754 64-bit double-precision floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

I'm not sure how you got that number without using `vpa()` in the first place, since 64-bit `double` is Matlab's maximum of precision...

You could use the [multiple precision toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6446) by Ben Barrowes, or [HPF](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class) by John d'Errico, also from the FEX. You'll have to convert/construct to/from string if you want to store/load it to/from file.

But I have to agree with John's comment there:

> The fact is, most of the time, if you can't do it with a double, you
>   are doing something wrong

so...*why* exactly are those 32-or-more digits important?

Comment: actually they are not so important, because I'm looking for the optimum parameter for a numerical technique that I've implemented (well-known in literature). My main issue is that `fminsearch` which is inside `fminsearchbnd` finds a number with 32 digits. When I take the 'double' version of it, my solution is not optimized any more. So I can workaround that imposing to `fminsearch` to search a number with only 6 digits for example. But it seems to me that it is not possible, it didn't work even defining the TolX and TolFun options.. :(

Comment: @Nicholas: just for my understanding; can you post the result of `class(your_solution)`, where `your_solution` is the number returned by `fminsearchbnd`?

Comment: @Nicholas: `fminsearch` only returns doubles and only accepts doubles for its bounds. Unless `fminsearchbnd` has completely hacked it I'm not sure what you mean. If you want variable precision bounded minimization with constraints on the bounds, then I think Mathematica may be an easier solution. Their [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NMinimize.html) function supports Nelder-Mead and the other features of `fminsearchbnd`.