# How does Clojure on the JVM convert from a float to a double with trailing garbage digits?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I run:

```
(double (float 3.14159))
```

and I get:

```
3.141590118408203
```

If I run it down to:

```
(double (float 3.141))
```

I get:
    3.1410000324249268

By what method is this conversion happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to general precision problem with floating point operations; floating points on computers *do not map directly to decimal numbers*, so standard decimal display of floats and doubles is rounded. In other words; the float and double here have exactly the same value, but when displayed they are rounded differently.

```
=> (= (double (float 3.14159)) (float 3.14159))
true
```

On the JVM, [Why converting from float to double changes the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504833/why-converting-from-float-to-double-changes-the-value) and [Convert float to double without losing precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916081/convert-float-to-double-without-losing-precision) may help.