# Why casting give me these weird results Java?

Tags: java, casting

This is the code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      double x=5.6556464566546546546556465465465;
      float y=(float)x;
      double z=  1+y;
        System.out.println(x+"\n"+y+"\n"+z);
    }
}
```

and this is the output

```
5.6556464566546545
5.6556463
6.655646324157715
```

I can understand the value of x and y but z from where it got those fractional numbers after the 3??!

Thank you very much

Comment: The issue has a thorough discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504833/why-converting-from-float-to-double-changes-the-value. Hopefully it will answer your question.

Comment: you defined a double precision floating point and then cast it as single precision. that meant the extra precision got discarded. nothing weird here.

Comment: See also: [Is Floating Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Answer (score 1):

Floats are an approximation of the actual number in Java, due to the way they're stored. If you need exact values, use a [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.