# Matlab Double Precision Digits: Variable Editor vs. fprintf

Tags: matlab, variables, printf, precision

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227145/in-matlab-are-variables-really-double-precision-by-default), I was looking at the precision of double variables in Matlab. There, it is recommended to use `fprintf` to look at the variables more closely.

The strange thing is that the Variable Editor and `fprintf` show different results, fprintf shows one digit more.

```
% pi
Variable Editor:       3.141592653589793
fprintf('0.16f\n',pi): 3.1415926535897931
vpa('pi'):             3.1415926535897932384626433832795

% pi / 180
pi180 = pi/180
Variable Editor (pi180)      0.017453292519943
fprintf('%0.16f\n',pi180)    0.0174532925199433
vpa('pi/180')                0.017453292519943295769236907684886
```

Internally, Matlab seems to be working with the precision which is printed by fprintf

```
>> fprintf('%0.16f\n',0.0174532925199433*10) % value from fprintf
0.1745329251994330
>> fprintf('%0.16f\n',0.017453292519943*10)  % value from Variable Editor
0.1745329251994300
>> fprintf('%0.16f\n',pi180*10)              % internal calculation
0.1745329251994330
```

Why is that so?

If I use the precalculated `pi/180` in a function, should I use the value from fprintf or from the Variable Editor?

**tl;dr** In the Variable Editor, Matlab is truncating at 15 digits instead of 16.

Comment: I have accessed the variables in the Variable Editor by double clicking on it. That way, more digits are shown than with a specified `short` format. AFAIK the precision of the "double-click output" can't be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** Variables in MATLAB use double precision. The same precision is used for variables in both the Command Window and the Variable Editor. The only difference is the display format and the number of decimal places of accuracy you print it to.

---

MATLAB by default uses double precision for its variables. These variables in MATLAB are stored in the Workspace. Both the Command Window and the Variable Editor pull their variables from the same Workspace and hence underneath use the same precision.

The default format for displaying variables in the Variable Editor and the Command Window is the `short` format. You can check this for the Command Window with

```
>> get(0, 'format')
ans =
   short
```

and for the Variable Editor by going to `Preferences -> Variables -> Format`. The `short` format by default displays variables to 4 decimal places of accuracy.

It appears to me that you have changed the default display format for variables in your Variable Editor to the `long` format. This format displays double variables with 15 decimal places of accuracy. Both the `long` and `short` formats round variables, so `pi` which is `3.14159` gets rounded to `3.1416` because of the `9` in the 5th decimal place when displayed with the `short` format

```
>> format short
>> pi
ans =
    3.1416
```

This is directly equivalent to the output produced by `fprintf`

```
>> fprintf(1, '%.4f\n', pi);
3.1416
```

However, the `long` format, which I'm guessing, you've set as the default for your Variable Editor rounds to 15 decimal places and so displays

```
>> format long
>> pi
ans =
   3.141592653589793
```

which is directly equivalent to

```
>> fprintf(1, '%.15f\n', pi);
3.141592653589793
```

When you use `fprintf(1, '%.16f\n', pi);` you are printing `pi` to 16 decimal places and **not** 15 as specified by the `long` format. This is why your output is

```
>> fprintf(1, '%.16f\n', pi);
3.1415926535897931
```

Note, the `1` at the end of this. This is why the `3` directly preceding it isn't rounded to `4` when displayed in your Variable Editor.

#### Summary

- Variables in MATLAB by default use double precision
- MATLAB variables are stored in the Workspace
- Variables available in the Command Window and the Variable Editor both come from the Workspace and use the same precision

#### Precalculated Values

In MATLAB you should use the variable name `pi180` in function calls or when manipulating other numeric data. This will use double precision and eliminate any copy and paste errors that may arise by using values output by `fprintf` or in the Variable Editor.

#### `fprintf` Quirks

**tl;dr** MATLAB's `short` and `long` formats switch between the `%d`, `%.f`, `%.g` and `%.e` specifiers depending on the most appropriate method for the input.

---

@[horchler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2278029/horchler) pointed out that `%.f` is only directly equivalent to the `short` and `long` formats for specific inputs and this is true. There is **no** direct equivalent for **all** inputs between `fprintf` and MATLAB's `short` and `long` formats.

For instance let's look at `eps` and `100.5` and try to print the numbers exactly like MATLAB's `short` and `long` formats.

```
>> format short
>> eps
ans =
   2.2204e-16
>> 100.5
ans =
  100.5000
```

and

```
>> format long
>> eps
ans =
     2.220446049250313e-16
>> 100.5
ans =
     1.005000000000000e+02
```

Now we know from above that `fprintf(1, '%.4f\n', pi);` and  `fprintf(1, '%.15f\n', pi);` are directly equivalent to `short` and `long` respectively for `pi` but are they for `eps` and `100.5`

```
>> fprintf(1, '%.4f\n', eps);
0.0000
>> fprintf(1, '%.15f\n', eps);
0.000000000000000
>> fprintf(1, '%.4f\n', 100.5);
100.5000
>> fprintf(1, '%.15f\n', 100.5);
100.500000000000000
```

**No** they aren't the only direct equivalent is `fprintf(1, '%.4f\n', 100.5);`. What if we try with `%.g`?

```
>> fprintf(1, '%.4g\n', eps);
2.22e-16
>> fprintf(1, '%.15g\n', eps);
2.22044604925031e-16
>> fprintf(1, '%.4g\n', 100.5);
100.5
>> fprintf(1, '%.15g\n', 100.5);
100.5
```

Now none of the `fprintf` statements are directly equivalent. However, we can produce a direct equivalent for `eps` using the `long` format with

```
>> fprintf(1, '%.16g\n', eps);
2.220446049250313e-16
```

because the number directly following the `.` for the `%g` format specifier specifies the number of significant digits (including those preceding the decimal point, `.`) we need to use *16* and not *15*.

To produce a direct equivalent for all of these input types for the `short` format we need to mix the `%.f`, `%.g` and **`%.e`** specifiers as well as adjusting the [field width](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#input_argument_formatspec).

```
>> format short
>> pi
ans =
    3.1416
>> eps
ans =
   2.2204e-16
>> 100.5
ans =
  100.5000
>> fprintf(1, '%.4f\n', pi);
3.1416
>> fprintf(1, '%.5g\n', eps);
2.2204e-16
>> fprintf(1, '%.4f\n', 100.5);
100.5000
```

**Not trivial at all.** The same can be done for the `long` format.

```
>> format long
>> pi
ans =
   3.141592653589793
>> eps
ans =
     2.220446049250313e-16
>> 100.5
ans =
     1.005000000000000e+02
>> fprintf(1, '%.15f\n', pi);
3.141592653589793
>> fprintf(1, '%.16g\n', eps);
2.220446049250313e-16
>> fprintf(1, '%.15e\n', 100.5);
1.005000000000000e+02
```

Even worse than for the `short` format.

So in short, MATLAB's `short` and `long` formats switch between the `%d`, `%.f`, `%.g` and `%.e` specifiers depending on the most appropriate method for the input.

#### Additional Reading

You can find information on the different display formats available in MATLAB through the [`format` documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html). There is also a helpful document on [Display Format for Numeric Values](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-format-for-numeric-values.html). And lastly, there is information about the [Variable Editor and its preferences](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/set-workspace-and-variable-preferences.html).

Comment: So there is no way to display double variables in the workspace or variable editor with full precision without fprintf. :)

Comment: With more than 15 decimal places of accuracy, no.

Comment: Your `fprintf` examples are only "directly equivalent" for a range of values. The `%g` option needs to be used for the general case, and even so, I'm not sure what Matlab prints is only based on that.

Comment: @horchler You are correct my examples are only directly equivalent for specific values. The `%g` option doesn't cover the general case though. MATLAB's `short` and `long` formats alternate between `%d`, `%.f`, `%.g` and `%.e` depending on the input. I've updated the answer with a section reflecting this.