# Matlab single to double conversion error

Tags: matlab, casting, floating-point, double, precision

Does someone know why casting `double()` on a single precision floating point number in Matlab (R2016a) changes the last digits? Here is an example:

```
format 'long'
x=3.2530601; %arbitrary single precision number
x_s=single(x);
x_d=double(x_s);
```

If I look at the classes and values of the variables, I can see the following:
`x` and `x_d` are doubles, `x_s` is single as expected. The values are:

```
x=3.253060100000000
x_s=3.2530601
x_d=3.253060102462769
```

Since the number `3.2530601` can be represented as a double or single precision floating point number, I don't understant why `x` and `x_d` are not the same. They are further away than `x+eps(x)`. I thought maybe Matlab tries to work out the double precision `x_d` by rational fraction approximation, but calling `rat(x,16)` does not give the same result as `x_d`. I'm clueless. Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: I do not use Matlab, so I am entering this hypothesis as a comment rather than an answer. 3.2530601 cannot be represented in single or double precision floating-point. This decimal numeral is converted to binary floating point, and the result is not exactly 3.2530601. Matlab uses the type, single or double, to decide how many digits to show by default. When the value is a single, Matlab shows just “3.2530601”. When the value is converted to a double, the value does not change, but Matlab shows more digits from it. The additional digits enable you to see the value is not 3.2530601.

Comment: Yes they are further away than x+eps(x).  However, they are not further away than x+eps(x_s).   eps(x_s) is 2.4e-7   The "error" in your conversion is 2.4e-9 which is less.   Basically when you convert it to single first 2.4e-7 is as accurate as you can get.  So then casting it back to double that is all you really can expect.

Comment: Thank you for these comments. You are all correct. It turns out it was a mistake to think Matlab would show all the decimals of a floating point number with `format 'long'`. Using `num2str(x_s,16)` reveals that `x_d` and `x_s` are the same up to 16 digits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two closely-related questions ([In MATLAB, are variables REALLY double-precision by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4227145/52738) and [Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/52738)), that you should be aware of, but this isn't *quite* covered fully by either of them...

When you calculate the decimal equivalent for a given significand and exponent of a [floating-point value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), you can calculate it out to as many decimal places as you want, but any places beyond the [floating-point relative accuracy](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) are ultimately of no real value and are typically not even displayed. However, they seem to come into play here when converting a lower-precision number to a higher-precision number.

Let's look at your value for `x_s`, both as it is displayed normally (only showing significant digits) and how [`vpa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) would display it (with an arbitrary number of digits):

```
>> x_s = single(3.2530601)  % Create a single-precision number

x_s =

  single

   3.2530601

>> eps(x_s)  % Floating-point relative accuracy

ans =

  single

   2.3841858e-07

>> vpa(x_s, 16)  % Show 16 digits of precision, way more than the relative accuracy

ans =

3.253060102462769

>> x_d = double(x_s)  % Convert to double-precision

x_d =

   3.253060102462769
```

Look at that! The digits from `vpa` match the digits gotten when converting to double-precision. It would appear that, when converting from a `single` to a `double`, MATLAB calculates the decimal equivalent of the lower-precision value out to the number of digits for the higher-precision value, and uses that to initialize it.